# Store data in IOS project

Tags: ios

I am new in ios programming.

I want to implement a dictionary. I have csv table with words and definitions. What is the best way to store my data in app? Is it better to use some frameworks as Realm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm really is the fastest database, but 99% happened Core Data with excellent documentation from Apple is a better solution, and even more so if you are a beginner it is better to study the native solutions offered by Apple and then the experience goes to third-party solutions. In this particular case, I expect that it will be better to use Core Data because if you have a large vocabulary UserDefaults it will be a long process the request

Answer (score 2):

To store data you can use either UserDefaults or Core Data. UserDefaults is used for storing small pieces of data such as settings, preferences, and individual values. While Core Data to used to store a large list of elements.
In you case I think you can use UserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

If you would to create a DataBase, you can use a local **JSON** (see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NfijT6mt6A&t)) or you can use **.plist**

Answer (score 1):

(1)   **xx.plist**     :  suit save  basic data eg:NSArray NSDictionary ect.

(2)**NSUserDefaults** : suit some active signal information.

(3) **xx.geojson**    : suit json string data in local

(4)**NSKeyedArchiver**: suit custom data .

(5)**coredata**      :  suit the table list data . you could use sql .